# Creating a list of 6 every possible combination

Tags: python

How would I create a list of 6 columns from a dataframe of 21 columns. I need to create every single combination possible and store these combinations is a dataframe.

Suppose

```
lst = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4','c5', 'c6', 'c7','c8', 'c9', 'c10', 'c11','c12', 'c13', 'c14','c15', 'c16', 'c17', 'c18','c19', 'c20', 'c21'] 

# Calling DataFrame constructor on list 
df = pd.DataFrame(lst) 

Some list generator
adds new list to cdf dataframe

final df should be something like this not sure if i wrote this in the right syntax but a dataframe with 1 column haveing a list of 6 elements
cdf = [[c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4','c5', 'c6'],['c7','c8', 'c9', 'c10', 'c11','c12'], ['c13', 'c14','c15', 'c16', 'c17', 'c18']...]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the combinations work in pure python, using the `itertools.combinations` function, documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). You can then import that list of tuples into pandas if desired.

Example code, which generates the combinations (combos are in sorted order, no repeated elements), prints how many combinations there are, and shows the first 2 and last 2 as examples:

```
import itertools
lst = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4','c5', 'c6', 'c7','c8', 'c9', 'c10', 'c11','c12', 'c13', 'c14','c15', 'c16', 'c17', 'c18','c19', 'c20', 'c21']

combos = itertools.combinations(lst, 6)
combos_list = list(combos)
print(f'{len(combos_list)} Combinations')
print(combos_list[0])
print(combos_list[1])
print(combos_list[-2])
print(combos_list[-1])
```

This generates output:

```
54264 Combinations
('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6')
('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c7')
('c15', 'c17', 'c18', 'c19', 'c20', 'c21')
('c16', 'c17', 'c18', 'c19', 'c20', 'c21')
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Glad to help! Feel free to upvote, and have a great Friday!